# Why is the destructor being called during copy assignmment?

Tags: c++

I have defined the following two C++ structs, `Room` and `House`. `House` contains a `std::list<Room>`.

I create a `House` object with `new`. I create a new `Room` with `new`. I create another `House` object with `new` and attempt to assign the previous `House` to this one. But for some reason the `House` destructor gets called... why?

(and then I also get a seg fault).

```
struct Room
{
   Room()
   : pString(0)
   {
     std::cout << "Room ctor [" << std::hex << this << "]\n";
   }
   Room(const Room& other)
   {
     std::cout << "Room COPY ctor [" << std::hex << this << "] other: " << std::hex << &other << "]\n";
     if(other.pString)
     {
        if(pString)
            delete pString;
        pString = strdup(other.pString);
     }
   }
   Room operator=(const Room& other)
   {
     std::cout << "Room ASSIGNMENT operator [" << std::hex << this << "] other: " << std::hex << &other << "]\n";
     if(this != &other)
     {
         if(other.pString)
         {
            if(pString)
                delete pString;
            pString = strdup(other.pString);
         }
      }
   }

  ~Room()
   { 
     std::cout << "Room dtor [" << std::hex << this << "]\n";
     if(pString)
        delete pString;
   }
   char * pString;
};

/// House struct ////////////////////////////
struct House
{
   House()
   {
     std::cout << "House ctor [" << std::hex << this << "]\n";
   }
   House(const House& other)
   {
     std::cout << "House COPY ctor [" << std::hex << this << "] other: " << std::hex << &other << "]\n";
     roomlist = other.roomlist;
   }
   House operator=(const House& other)
   {
     std::cout << "House ASSIGNMENT ctor [" << std::hex << this << "] other: " << std::hex << &other << "]\n";
     if(this != &other)
     {
       roomlist = other.roomlist;
     }
   }

  ~House()
   { 
     std::cout << "House dtor [" << std::hex << this << "]\n";
   }
   std::list<Room> roomlist;
};
```

The code to test this is below:

```
       House * pCurHouse = new House;          
       Room * pIkeaRm = new Room;
       pIkeaRm->pString = strdup("IKEA ROOM");
       std::cout << "Room created\n\n\n";
       pCurHouse->roomlist.push_back(*pIkeaRm);
       House * pOtherHouse = new House;       


       std::cout << "assigning current house to this house... \n";
       *pOtherHouse = *pCurHouse;
       std::cout << "House assigned. \n\n\n";
```

I never see the debug "House assigned". I see instead:

```
assigning current house to this house... 
House ASSIGNMENT operator [0x20753a0] other: 0x2075210]
Room COPY constructor [0x2075400] other: 0x2075310]
House destructor [0x7fff36a7a6a0]   //// which House object is that????
Room destructor [0x402580]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Room copy constructor never initializes `pString`, and later deletes it (null check is useless on uninitialized pointer), undefined behavior ensues.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `new` so much? Is there any reason you're using `new` at all?

Comment: @Benjamin, well eventually I'll put a `House` member inside another class, and at certain times I want to be able to replace that `House` member wiht another `House`. I thought pointers could be useful here (to delete the old values). Is there a better way...?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just assigning from the new house to the current house?

Comment: You must not `delete` a pointer you got from `strdup`.  You should `free` it instead.  Even better, just use `std::string` and don't worry about allocation details.

Comment: @Benjamin, hmmm I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the destructor of the return value of your `House House::operator=` method. You forgot however the return statements in both of your assignment operators (usually `return *this;`), and hence the crash. As noted in the comments by [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) of course usually you also return a reference, not a copy.

Comment: Also, it would be much better for `operator=` to return `House&` or `Room&` . It doesn't make any sense for it to return another copy of the object.